# One-to-one-optional self-referencing relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I faced the following domain model

```
public class Transaction
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public decimal TransactionSum { get; set; }
    public decimal TransactionCurrencyConversionRatio { get; set; }
    public bool IsTransactionApprovedBySystem { get; set; }
    public bool IsTransactionApprovedBySender { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionInitiatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ? TransactionApprovedDate { get; set; }
    public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }

    public Account SenderAccount { get; set; }
    public Account ReceiverAccount { get; set; }
    public Guid SenderAccountId { get; set; }
    public Guid ReceiverAccountId { get; set; }
    public Transaction CommissionTransactionForRealTransaction { get; set; }
    public Guid ? CommissionTransactionForRealTransactionId { get; set; }
}
```

It means, that every transaction is Client-to-Client transaction OR CommssionFee transaction(commision for transaction between client-to-client transaction), it described in TransactionType property, which is enum type.

Example: Bob transfer 100$ to Alice, system charge 1$ for this transfer service, so 2 rows added for this operation:

Transaction #XXX1 - 100$ and it has type Client-To-Client and property CommissionTransactionForRealTransaction  is NULL, therefore CommissionTransactionForRealTransactionId attribute in table set to NULL.

Transaction #XXX2 - 1$ and it had type CommissionFee, and property CommissionTransactionForRealTransaction is referencing another object, while CommissionTransactionForRealTransactionId in table has some foreign key.

I read documentation and examples in MSDN on EF Core relationship section, but have no idea how to implement 0...1 to 1 self-referencing. I started with this code:

```
builder.HasOne(p => p.CommissionTransactionForRealTransaction)
    .WithOne(p => p.???);
```

Comment: You don't need the manual configuration. EF already understands `Guid? CommissionTransactionForRealTransactionId` with `Transaction CommissionTransactionForRealTransaction`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Convention over configuration doesn't work here, because while EC Core conventionally will identify those as reference and FK property, the conventional relationship is one-to-many/ While OP needs one-to-one, so manual configuration is definitely needed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Write your fluent API configuration as follows:

```
builder.HasOne(tr => tr.CommissionTransactionForRealTransaction)
       .WithOne().HasForeignKey<Transaction>(tr => tr.CommissionTransactionForRealTransactionId)
       .IsRequired(false);
```

It should work for you.

Comment: (1) *"Write your fluent API configuration as follows"* **Why?** (2) *"It should work for you"* **Should** or **will** work?

Comment: `"It should work for you" Should or will work?`-Will work! I have generated in my side.

Comment: @IvanStoev Dear! Are you now concerned about my language? :)

Comment: Then what is the difference between `Should` or `Will` they both them are proving that the answer is what the questioner wants.

Comment: As I commented before, I'm concerned that you are including things in your answers which sound like are mandatory, while they are not. For instance here, `WithOne()` is enough (with explanation why) @Aria I'm not native English speaker, but to me "should" sounds like the   answerer is unsure if their solution works or not (similar to "try this"). In other words, its unclear if they know/tested the solution, and expect OP to do that. Which is not helpful for future readers.

Comment: @IvanStoev Dear, you are making things complicated! `It should work` means that it has worked in my side and also will work for you if no external agent take a influence here. Please take it easy. By the way, I like your approach.

Comment: Hey @Tanvir, as you can see I'm just commenting to help you improve your answers. Otherwise I could have simply DV w/o any explanation :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Off course! I believe that you are a very wonderful and helpful guy.  I always take both inspiration and suggestion from your comments and answer as you are much more expert than me.. I always appreciate your help.

Comment: @IvanStoev By the way, `WithOne()` vs `WithOne().HasForeignKey<Transaction>(tr => tr.CommissionTransactionForRealTransactionId)`.--This is because I told you that I always like to be explicit. Yes! `WithOne()` is sufficient here because he is following the EF ForeignKey naming convention. Now think about someone came to this answer who did not followed the EF ForeignKey naming convention. then?

Comment: The key word is "I", i.e. to be explicit is just *your* personal opinion. It doesn't hurt to be explicit, the point is that it is redundant/unnecessary/not mandatory, hence falls into opinion-based category, which is not tolerated on SO (at least in questions - there is a special close vote reason). Regarding your last question - the EF Core is built around convention over configuration principle. In other words, configuration is needed only when the convention doesn't work and has to be overridden. If a person have FK not following the convention, they **have** to map it using the proper API.

Comment: @IvanStoev `If a person have FK not following the convention, they have to map it using the proper API.`  Yes! That's why I have made this because may be someone will come to this answer in future who did not the follow the convention. Thank you for all conversation.

Comment: Mapping the FK is not part of this question/problem, so it's unlikely someone with *that* issue to come to *this* question/answer. Anyway, you are improving - at least this time you don't change the OP model :) Who knows, may be the next time you'll not include redundant things :) Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much!